# Extending Seed Job dsl

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I’m currently having a DSL Seed Job which creates corresponding new Jenkins jobs for every new SVN branch created. I would like to leverage the Job dsl to manage my organization’s Jenkins.

Like a having Parent seed job and the respective application’s seed job’s extending the Parent seed job. Is it possible with job dsl.

Have any one implemented a similar structure ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have run things that way and it works pretty well. It makes things easy to have one seed job that manages multiple seed jobs.

I would recommend keep the "master seed job" in a separate repository, that way it's easier to roll back if you introduce breaking changes.

Documentation here is helpful: https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.dsl

```
job('example-1') {
steps {
    dsl {
        external('projectC.groovy')
    }
}
```

}

That will create a job that will run the dsl script "projectC.groovy"

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, Could you pls let me if that's okay what exactly you did and how. I'm really excited to know. Thanks.

Comment: it's all in the documentation. job('example-1') {
    steps {
        dsl {
            external('projectA.groovy', 'projectB.groovy')
            external('projectC.groovy')
            removeAction('DISABLE')
            ignoreExisting()
            additionalClasspath('lib')
        }
    }
}